# Exception: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Quota Exceeded) in bot framework channel emulator

Tags: window

I download the file from https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder and run Microsoft.Bot.Sample.AlarmBot and then run the emulator. The emulator should show a list of option for me to choose from but instead it show the error. Can anyone help me? Thank you. The screenshot here show the problem below.

[image]

Comment: The emulator is the bot framework channel emulator

Comment: The environment is visual studio 2017 c#

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the AlarmBot sample untouched, it has an embedded key in it that was a sample key good only for 1000 uses a month, so other users have probably used all of its quota.

You can go to the LUIS portal and create a new App - the Programmatic API key it gives you can be used as a subscription key for 1000 uses. Set it up in the LUIS portal, then update your sample app and the bot should work.